# Declaring an Array using Variables and the array() construct in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, declaration

I'm sure this has been asked before but I can't find it.  The PHP documentation unclear on this and I can't find any examples like this.  Is it legal to use variables in the declaration of an array use the array() construct?  Not as keys, as the values.  Like this:

```
function myFunc($value1, $value2, $value3) {
    $myArr = array('value1' => $value1, 'value2' => $value2, 'value3' => $value3);
    return $myArr;
}
```

Is that legal?

Comment: Provided example is completely valid. Why can't you just test it by yourself and get the answer yourself? :)

Comment: Well, if for no other reason, now there is a searchable record of it on the web.  So someone who went looking like I did will find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is legal. Otherwise you would get an error.

Comment: I'm not to the point of running it yet, and won't be for a little while.  I wanted to make sure this was legal before I wrote a whole bunch more code based on it.  I just couldn't find an example of it used on the web or in the PHP documentation.  And the documentation was a little vague on the issue.

Comment: @Alcon: You’re right. The lack of a clear language grammar is sometimes really bugging.

Answer (score 3):

both keys and values can be arbitrary expressions*

```
 $r = array(
     phpversion() => 1 + 2 - 3,
 );
```

- except that keys cannot be arrays/objects/resources

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's absolutely legal! You can also use variables for the key names:

```
$myArr = array($thekey => $theval);
```

The key or value for any key/value pair doesn't need to be in any particular format, it just needs to evaluate out to a primitive type (i.e.: a number or string). The `array()` construct simply looks for the "simplified" values that it's passed; it doesn't care what they are or how they got there.

Hope this helps!